# Is there a better way to implement displaying different views based on view picker selection?

Tags: swiftui

Please take a look at the following code and tell me this. 
1. Is there a better way to implement this functionality? 
2. I know **AnyView** has a performance impact, but if there isn't a better way to apply the **SRP**, does the performance impact worth it?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewPicker = ViewPicker()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("View Picker", selection: $viewPicker.selectionIndex) {
                Text("Days").tag(0)
                Text("Months").tag(1)
                Text("Years").tag(2)
            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())

            viewPicker.pick()
        }

    }
}

struct DayView: View {
    var body: some View { Text("Day View") }
}

struct MonthView: View {
    var body: some View { Text("Month View") }
}

struct YearView: View {
    var body: some View { Text("Year View") }
}


//MARK:- View Picker
class ViewPicker: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectionIndex = 0

    func pick() -> AnyView {
        switch selectionIndex {
        case 0:
            return AnyView(DayView())
        case 1:
            return AnyView(MonthView())
        case 2:
            return AnyView(YearView())
        default:
            return AnyView(Text("Unknown"))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go that way, the following looks more appropriate for me (from the SwiftUI design perspective)

Tested with Xcode 11.4

```
class ViewPicker: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectionIndex = 0

    func pick() -> some View {
        Group {
            if selectionIndex == 0 {
                DayView()
            }
            if selectionIndex == 1 {
                MonthView()
            }
            if selectionIndex == 2 {
                YearView()
            }
            if selectionIndex > 2 {
                Text("Unknown")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great. this doesn't hide the details of the view like the "AnyView" struct from SwiftUI, so it doesn't have the "AnyView" performance impact, right? Do you have a better way? I open to suggestions.

Comment: Like Asperi answered, using Group & AnyView is the only 2 options for now

Comment: Ok, is "Group" better than "AnyView" for the reasons I've mentioned or they're the same?